# How to melt a dataframe into multiple factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2, melt

I have been trying to plot a line plot with ggplot.

My data looks something like this:

```
        I04 F04 I05 F05 I06 F06
CAT     3   12  2   6   6   20
DOG     0   0   0   0   0   0
BIEBER  1   0   0   1   0   0
```

and can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/npg33kbnjpjudhc/mydata.csv?dl=0).

Basically, we have a certain number of `CAT`s (or other creatures) initially in a year (this is `I04`), and a certain number of `CAT`s at the end of the year (this is `F04`). This goes on for some time.

I can plot something like this fairly simply using the code below, and get this:

[image]

This is fantastic, but doesn't work very well for me. After all, I have these staring and ending inventory for each year. So I am interested in seeing how the initial values (`I04, I05, I06`) change over time. So, for each animal, I would like to create two different lines, one for initial quantity and one for final quantity (`F01, F05, F06`). This seems to me like now I have to consider two factors.

This is really difficult given the way my data is set up. I'm not sure how to tell ggplot that all the `I` prefixed years are one factor, and all the `F` prefixed years are another factor. When the dataframe gets melted, it's too late. I'm not sure how to control this situation.

Any advice on how I can separate these values or perhaps another, better way to tackle this situation?

Here is the code I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

DF <- read.csv("mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## cleaning up, converting factors to numeric, etc
text_names <- data.frame(as.character(DF$animals))
names(text_names) <- c("animals")
numeric_cols <- DF[, -c(1)]
numeric_cols <- sapply(numeric_cols, as.numeric)
plot_me <- data.frame(cbind(text_names, numeric_cols))
plot_me$animals <- as.factor(plot_me$animals)
meltedDF <- melt(plot_me)

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_line(aes(seq(1:36), meltedDF$value, group=meltedDF$animals, color=meltedDF$animals))
p
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original data from the link:

```
nd <- reshape(mydata, idvar = "animals", direction = "long", varying = names(mydata)[-1], sep = "")
ggplot(nd, aes(x = time, y = I, group = animals, colour = animals)) + geom_line() + ggtitle("Development of initial inventories")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(nd, aes(x = time, y = F, group = animals, colour = animals)) + geom_line() + ggtitle("Development of final inventories")
```

[image]

Comment: where did 'time' come from?

Comment: The `time` is the result of applying the `reshape`. The function guesses this variable using the supplied value for `sep`, in our case just `""`. Is the plot what you expected?

Comment: Why did you choose to use `reshape` instead of `melt`?

Comment: Because so the `I`'s and the `F`'s are nor separated, and you want separate plots for them, or?

Comment: @MattO'Brien, there are times when `reshape` may make more sense than `melt` (until "data.table" version 1.9.8 comes out with its own version of `melt`). In particular, `reshape` allows you to get a "semi-long" version of your dataset, where you have a set of "id" columns, and one column for each type of measurement. `melt`, on the other hand, might squash all those different measurement variables into a single long variable.

Comment: @RStudent, you may also be interested in `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. Usage here would be something like: `merged.stack(DF, var.stubs = c("I", "F"), sep = "var.stubs")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think from a data analyst perspective the following approach might provide better insight.

For each animal we visualize the initial and the final quantity in a separate panel. Moreover, each subplot has its own y scale because the values of the different animal types are radically different. Like this, differences within and across animal types are easier to spot.

Given the current structure of your data, we do not need two different factors. After the `gather` call the `indicator` column includes data like I04, F04, etc. We just need to `separate` the first character from the rest resulting in two columns `type` and `time`. We can use `type` as the argument for `color` in the `ggplot` call. `time` provides a unified x-axis across all animal types.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% gather(indicator, value, -animals) %>% 
  separate(indicator, c('type', 'time'), sep = 1) %>%
  mutate(
    time = as.numeric(time)
    ) %>% ggplot(aes(time, value, color = type)) +
            geom_line() + 
            facet_grid(animals ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Of course, you might also do it the other way round, namely using a subplot for the initial and the final quantities like this:

```
data %>% gather(indicator, value, -animals) %>% 
  separate(indicator, c('type', 'time'), sep=1) %>%
  mutate(
    time = as.numeric(time)
    ) %>% ggplot(aes(time, value, color = animals)) +
            geom_line() + 
            facet_grid(type ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

But as described above, I would not recommend that because the y scale varies too much across animal types.